# How to get OpenFire user login session ids?

Tags: php, xmpp, reverse-engineering, openfire, smack

Whenever a client logins to a server, the server associates the client with a "session".

Where does OpenFire store these session keys and/or ids? How can we retrieve them?

There doesn't seem to be a session table in the [entire list of OpenFire database tables](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database-guide.html#ofGroup). Is the session information stored only in the server's ram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openfire store the sessions only in memory and don't save that in DB. 
You could create an openfire plugin, which provide the user sessions (e.g. over REST).

Guide, how to create a plugin: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html

SessionManager class you need: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/SessionManager.html

Comment: Isn't there a plugin like this (already written by someone else) which we could already use?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you create one, please provide that to the openfire community.